# How to Implement Progress Bar for Long Running HTTP Request

Tags: c#, html, http, asynchronous, progress-bar

I have an HTTP server written in C# based off the HttpListenerContext class. The server is for processing binary log files and converting them to text, and can take quite a long time to do the conversion. I would like to indicate progress back to the user, but I am unsure on the best way to do this. On the server side, in handling my HTTP request, I essentially have this function:

```
    public async Task HandleRequest()
    {
        try
        {
            await ProcessRequest();
        }
        catch (HttpListenerException)
        {
            // Something happened to the http connection, don't try to send anything
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            SendFailureResponse(500);
        }
    }
```

Currently, ProcessRequest() sends the HTML response when finished, but I would like to essentially add the [IProgress](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx) interface to the function and somehow indicate that progress back to the Web client. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it would be to store progress on server side and periodically pull the information from client.

However, if you want the server to notify the client ( push ), then you will need to implement some kind of bi-directional communication between the server and client  (I am currently using ASP.NET Web API and SignalR to achieve this at work).

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I got I'll try to explain and I hope you notice its not FULL FULL complete, you'll have to understand the logic behind this and accept or not as a plausible option.

**The Method:** Set a custom object to store progress of your ongoing operations, make a global static list containing this metadata. *Notice how I track them with Ids: I don't store that on DB, the natural act of instantiating the class will auto_increment their Id.*
Then, you can add a new controller to respond the progress of a particular ongoing process.
Now that you have a controller to respond the progress of an ongoing process by Id, you can create a javascript timer to call it and update the DOM.
When creating your process, dont hold the htmlrequest until its over, open a background operation instead and just respond with the newly created ProgressTracker.Id, through that class/list you can keep track of the progress and reply accordingly.
As said in another answer, when an operation finishes you can send a push notification and the clientside javascript will interrupt the timers and proceed to the next view/result/page, or you can increment the looping timer to detect when its done and call the results from another controller. (this way you can avoid using push if needed.)

Here is the partial code:

```
public class ProgressTracker {
    private static GlobalIdProvider = 0;
    public int _id = ++GlobalIdProvider;
    public int Id { get { return _id; } }
    bool IsInProgress = false;
    bool IsComplete = false;
    float Progress;
    public YourProgressObject Data;
}

public class GlobalStatic {
    public static List<ProgressTracker> FooOperations = new List<ProgressTracker>();
}

public class SomeWebApiController {
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetProgress(int Id) {
        var query = (from a in GlobalStatic.FooOperations where a.Id==Id select a);
        if(!query.Any()) {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "No operation with this Id found.");
        } else {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Ok, query.First());
        }
    }
}

// this is javascript
// ... Your code until it starts the process.
// You'll have to get the ProgressTracker Id from the server somehow.
var InProgress = true; 
window.setTimeout(function(e) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = "<myHostSomething>/SomeWebApiController/GetProgress?Id="+theId;
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Authentication","bearer "+localStorage.getItem("access_token"));

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            updateProgressBar(data);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();

    function updateProgressBar(data) {
        document.getElementById("myProgressText").innerHTML = data.Progress;
    }
}, 3000);
```

Disclaimer: If my javascript is shitty, pardon me but I'm too used to using jQuery and all this fancy stuff x_x